# How would you simplify this $\exp,\,\ln$ problem

Tags: logarithms

$$\exp\exp\exp\exp\ln\ln\ln\ln3$$

The issue is that $\ln\ln\ln3<0$ so we can't take the natural log and can't just cancel the $\exp$s because it's undefined.

I do know however that $\ln x$ when $x<0$ equals $\ln(|x|)+i\pi$, meaning the original expression could be written as $\exp\exp\exp\exp(\ln(-\ln\ln\ln3)+i\pi)$, which I was hoping could be simplified but I can't figure anything out.

Also know about the “most beautiful equation in math” $e^{iπ}+1=0$ which might be useful here

I’m not sure. Maybe it can't be simplified into an exact answer.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: "court natural log"?

Comment: Regardless of which branch of $\ln$ you choose, for $z\ne 0$, $\exp(\ln z) = z$. Function composition is associative, so this should always come out to $3$.